# angularjs ng-pattern for input[email] doesn't work as expected

Tags: javascript, angularjs, design-patterns, input

I want to allow ANYTHING, including invalid emails (without @, empty, etc)

https://jsfiddle.net/pb45k5xa/2/

I'm using:

```
ng-pattern="/.*?/"
```

But it doesn't works until you don't put an `*@*` (like `a@b`) in the input.

How can I avoid this?

Answer (score 0):

```
<input type="email" ng-pattern="/.*?/" ng-model="email" placeholder="Enter an email here">
```

Here `type="email"` performs a validation on its own. If you want to allow the user to type anything, just use a regular input without `type="email"` nor `ng-pattern="/.*?/"`.

Comment: I cannot remove the type="email" because it's useful for mobile (the email inputs uses another keyboard (that includes the "@" character in the main view, etc)

Comment: I understand. You should edit your question to add this clarification. Anyway, I think the answer you posted is the correct way to go.

Answer (score 0):

```
module.directive('ngRemoveEmailValidation', function(){
        return {
            require : 'ngModel',
            link : function(scope, element, attrs, ngModel) {
                ngModel.$validators["email"] = function () {
                    return true;
                };
            }
        }
    });
```

I'm using this directive to "bypass" the validators